# Why do I keep getting syntax error in my bash script? Does it have something related to the ":"?

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I'm trying to count the errors for each item in my errorList array, but I keep getting the "syntax error in expression (error token is ": just a test")".

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a errorList=(
    'MEDIA ERROR: just a test'
    'MEDIA BLA: resource unavaliable!'
    'DIALOG: Found PROBLEM ev_id="EV_ID"'
    )

declare -a errorListNames=(
    "Silence"
    "Unavaliable"
    "Environment error"
    )

pathLogs="/home/logs_test/"
logFileName="media.log.*"

dateLog="10-10-2019"

fgrep "$dateLog" $pathLogs$logFileName > grepedByDate.txt

for i in "${errorList[@]}"
    do
        fgrep -c "${ errorList[i], }" grepedByDate.txt
        echo "${errorListNames[i]}"
    done

echo "Bye"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Use `!` or `#` to obtain keys

Instead of:

```
for i in "${errorList[@]}"
```

use:

```
for i in ${!errorList[@]}"
```

or:

```
maxIndex=${#errorList[@]}
for (( i=0; i<$maxIndex; i++ ))
```

### 2. Whitespace is significant inside variable references

Instead of:

```
        fgrep -c "${ errorList[i], }" grepedByDate.txt
```

use:

```
        fgrep -c "${errorList[i]}" grepedByDate.txt
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I was at it for a while now. If it is not asking too much, I didn't get the difference between `${errorList[@]}` and `${!errorList[@]}`, could you help me here?

Comment: `for i in "${errorList[@]}"; do echo "i=[$i]"; done; for i in "${!errorList[@]}"; do echo "i=[$i]"; done` ?

Comment: `${errorList[@]}` is the list of values, whereas `${!errorList[@]}` is the list of indexes from the  `errorList` array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an associative array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A errors=(
    [Unavailable]='MEDIA ERROR: Resource unavailable'
)

for i in "${!errors[@]}"; do
    echo "$i: ${errors[$i]}"
done
```

- `${!errors[@]}` expands to keys (`Unavailable`, ...) and is stored in `$i`
- `${errors[$i]}` expands to values for the given key `$i` (`MEDIA ERROR...`, ...)